# Webpack publicPath не работает

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

У меня такая проблема что при сборке пути изображений в css не генерируются по моим заданным правилам. Вместо указанного пути в PublicPath webpack генерирует хеш с расширением изображения, который даже не открывается. Кажется webpack сжимает файл, но перебарщивает что изображения не открываются.

В начале создания проекта я хотел что-бы webpack автоматически сжимал и конвертировал в webp формат и установил несколько плагинов и внёс несколько правил в файл конфигураций. Но позже оно мне не понадобилась и я удалил плагины и настройки в конфиге.

Может ли это влиять? Хотя я всё удалил.

Файл конфигураций

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const copyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

const Paths = {
  src: path.join(__dirname, "../src"),
  dist: path.join(__dirname, "../dist"),
  assets: "assets/",
};

module.exports = {
  externals: {
    paths: Paths,
  },
  entry: {
    home: `${Paths.src}/js/home.js`,
    main: `${Paths.src}/index.js`
  },
  output: {
    filename: `${Paths.assets}js/[name].js`,
    path: Paths.dist,
    publicPath: "",
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        exclude: "/node_modules/",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[path][name].[ext]",
          context: "src/",
          outputPath: 'assets/',
          publicPath: "../",
          useRelativePaths: true,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: `[path][name]_[contenthash:8].[ext]`,
          context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
          outputPath: 'assets/',
          publicPath: '../',
          useRelativePaths: true,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: ["autoprefixer", "css-mqpacker", "cssnano"],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: { sourceMap: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: `${Paths.assets}css/[name].css`,
    }),
    new copyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: `${Paths.src}/img`, to: `${Paths.assets}img` },
        { from: `${Paths.src}/icons`, to: `${Paths.assets}icons` },
        { from: `${Paths.src}/libs`, to: `${Paths.dist}/libs` },
        { from: `${Paths.src}/static`, to: "" },
      ],
      options: {
        concurrency: 100,
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

package json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run build\" \"npm run ndmon\"",
    "dev": "webpack serve --open --config ./webpack/webpack.devs.conf.js",
    "build": "webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.build.conf.js -w",
    "ndmon": "nodemon index"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^9.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.3.2",
    "hbs": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "css-mqpacker": "^7.0.0",
    "cssnano": "^5.0.7",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "handlebars-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

Вот что я получаю

[image: Директория дист]

Вес изображения получили 45byte, а оригинал весит 95kb

С генерировавшийся путь в css: `body{background:url(82d9924ce7c7cb06a0d2.jpg)}`

Помогите решить эту проблему! Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Должно быть так - `publicPath: "/"`

Comment: Спасибо что ответили на мой вопрос, но я уже решил. Проблема была в css-loadr, установил предыдущую версию и всё заработало.